# About a MySql statement in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I use MySql database and I use eclipse Java and JDBC to connect. I have a question about SQL statement. I have a table and 4 columns which are id_desk, id_time, user_name and user_passwords. I want to get all informations (all columns information) by using user_name. HOw can i get one row's all informations?

Comment: here... http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: Look into PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 1):

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

//Put your table name instead of TABLE     
String query = "SELECT id_desk, id_time, user_name, user_passwords FROM TABLE WHERE user_name = ?";

try {
  //Provide your Database credentials
    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
  //Replace somename with whatever username you querying
    preparedStatement.setString(1,"somename");

    // execute select SQL stetement
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {

    //Here you will get the result of the query, ONE row at a time.

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {
     //Cleanup code
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you would want to use will be similar to:

```
Select id_desk, id_time, user_name, user_passwords FROM table 
WHERE user_name = (whatever your username is)
```

Storing pure user passwords in a database is not very secure, and you will almost always want to encode them in some way (there are countless resources online with examples of how to do this and why, google them).

Comment: i think simpler would be `Select * FROM table 
WHERE user_name = (whatever your username is)`

Comment: Simpler, yes, but i prefer not using the wildcard character.  If you were to alter your table later to have different columns, you could impact anything that uses a wildcard query, whereas this way you know the order and what gets returned